# Expectation of transition in a Markov process

Tags: conditional-probability, markov-process

I have the following transition matrix for a Discrete Markov process with 3 states, say states A, B and C:

\begin{bmatrix}0.985992 &  0.0134092 & 0.000599272\\
               0.0265225 &  0.949748 & 0.0237297 \\
               0.00196398 & 0.0895138 & 0.908522
\end{bmatrix}

As I was doing some calculations I noticed that if I simulated data the number of transitions from any two states is roughly the same going both ways (e.g. the number of states going from A to B, A->B, is roughly the same as from B to A, B->A), for example for 100000 iterations:

- A->B: 8164 and B->A: 8340
- B->C: 7602 and C->B: 7779
- A->C: 365 and C->A: 188

In an intuitive way, Why is this? I understand it if I calculate the expectations, for example:

$\mathbb{E}(A \rightarrow B)=\pi_A P(B | A)$
and this is actually very close to $\mathbb{E}(B \rightarrow A)=\pi_B P(A | B)$, where $\pi_X$ is the stationary distribution for state $X$.

I just don't quite grasp why this happens. Any insights? Any reference or leads appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a peculiar property of your transition matrix, but it doesn't have to be that way.

If your system satisfies $\pi_A P(B|A) = \pi_B P(A|B)$ for all states $A$ and $B$, your system is said to satisfy the property of *detailed balance*. Transition matrices that satisfy this property, are called *reversible*.

But there are Markov chains with stationary distributions that don't satisfy this property. E.g., you could try to find a chain that has as stationary distribution the uniform distribution but a transition matrix that is not symmetric. That means, find a transition matrix where all rows and all columns sum to one, but that is not symmetric. A simple example would be:
$$
T = \left[\begin{matrix}
              0.1 & 0.1 & 0.8 \\
              0.2 & 0.8 &   0 \\
              0.7 & 0.1 & 0.2 \\
          \end{matrix}\right].
$$
Clearly, the stationary distribution is the uniform distribution $\pi_U = (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)$, and this Markov chain is not reversible.

A good, short introduction to Markov chains can be found e.g. in

> Bishop, Christopher M., and Nasser M. Nasrabadi. Pattern recognition and machine learning. Vol. 4. No. 4. New York: springer, 2006.